# Flickering Screen and Window rotating in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

When I Press Ctrl+Shift+E all windows are turning up like this. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I Installed Compiz. But until today it's working fine. But now it's making a problem. After this happen the screen keeps flickering.

I tried Disabling Use hardware acceleration when available in Google Chrome but it doesn't work.

[image]